# Why must a class which contains an abstract method be abstract?

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract

I don't understand why a class, which contains an abstract method, must be abstract.

Comment: If you have an abstract method, it means that this method is not yet implemented, so by definition the class is incomplete and hence is (and must be) abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To look at it another way, say your class with an abstract method did not have to be abstract, and you were allowed to instantiate it, what would the compiler to if you called that method? - there would be no actual code to run. That is why we declare the class abstract - we are marking it as 'not yet ready to use', and later create a 'concrete' subclass with zero abstract methods which can actually be used.

```
class Horse { // <== note not actually allowed...
   public abstract int getNeighCount();
}

Horse horse = new Horse();
horse.getNeighCount();  // <== what would happen here??
```

Comment: your explanation is really good thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

A concrete (non abstract) class must have implementations for all of its methods. Therefore an unimplemented (abstract) method can only be in an interface or in an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with any must. A class, that has at least one abstract method is abstract, that is the definition.

Answer (score 0):

By default even in your interface all the methods are abstract.

Abstract methods are meant to be overridden by subclasses of that abstract class to give a very specific implementation and is really a skeleton.